# Bootstrap 4, make columns fit into available vertical height

Tags: html, css, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a dynamic template that can change, and as an example can look something like this: [image: Template I'm trying to replicate]

I'm using bootstrap 4, and when trying to remake columns in code:

```html
<div class="row no-gutters">
        @forelse ($template->layout as $index => $blockArray)
            @php
                $block = $blocks->firstWhere('id', $blockArray['id']);
            @endphp

            <div class="col-{{ $block->width }}" style="height: {{ $blockHeight * $block->height }}vh">
                @php
                    $svg = $svgs[$block->settings['background_pattern']][$block->settings['background_pattern_font']];
                    $background = "url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg class=\"preview-svg\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" viewBox=\"{$svg['viewBox']}\" height=\"1em\" width=\"1.5em\" fill=\"" . urlencode("{$block->settings['background_pattern_color']}") . "\"><path d=\"{$svg['path']}\" /></svg>')";
                @endphp

                <div class="w-100 h-100"
                    style="background-image: {{ $background }}; background-color: {{ $block->settings['background_color'] }}; background-repeat: no-repeat;">
                    <div style="color: red">
                        {{ $index }}: {{ $block->id }} - {{ $block->width }} x
                        {{ $block->height }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        @empty
            No template for given platform has been set.
        @endforelse
    </div>
```

Here is how the rendered html looks like:

[image]

I get a problem that the blocks that are say to the left or right of "Block 2", don't fill up the available height, and leave a gap as such:

[image]

Is there a way, with **Bootstrap 4** to make the columns in the row to "float up" to fill up the available space?

I've tried using "d-block" on the row element, and "float-left/right" on the columns, but that breaks the order in image 1.